# Can Blazor connect to a local SignalR hub

Tags: blazor, signalr

I am writing a Blazor application, and I want to use a SignalR hub installed on the local client.  If the Blazor app is installed on a web server, can the app connect to the local hub?

In the Blazor app I specified the hub address as "localhost", but it requires that the app have the hub running on the server.  How do I specify the local client's IP address?

Comment: Did you look on Microsoft Learn before asking on SO?

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Yes, the "learn" information was helpful. I've been doing small SignalR projects, but this is the first time I've tried to connect from a server-based Blazor app to a local hub on another system. The Blazor app works properly if I self-host it on the same system as the hub.  I've made progress, and am able to determine the IP address of the client and then pass it to the hub start, but the start times-out.  No connection events are logged in the hub console window.  I've even turned off the Firewall.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!  The hub was listening on localhost, and the app was connecting to the hub IP address.  I changed the hub to use its actual IP address, and it started working.